# Can sleep be a barrier against aging?

Tags: sleep, senescence

I know that what I'm writing about may be a little strange, but as far as I know,when we are asleep, our human body is programmed to carry on biological functionalities in a really optimized way and we are less sensible to external stress.
So I wonder whether putting people in some state of induced coma for a long period of time (I mean for years) may reduce the effect of time and aging on their bodies to be able to awake them later ,almost as they were before undergoing the process ?

Note: I'm not speaking about the process of freezing bodies - only bare sleep.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I've edited to clarify grammar and formatting; please feel free to [edit] if my edits conflicted with your intents.  Also, if you could show more of the research which you have already done, it would probably help us understand the context of your question.  Thanks!